# Localize HTML text string file in ios from localizable.string(Italian)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Actually I am getting a string with HTML tags from the server in my app and I receive it in `NSString` then I pass this string to a `UIWebView` to show the data as HTML.

I want to localize these string in to Italian language.

How can I localize this HTML string?

Comment: String is---<html> <head><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='cummins_black.css' /><p><span style="font-size: 18px; font-family: helvetica;">Higher-than-normal exhaust </span><br /><span style="font-size: 18px; font-family: helvetica;">temperatures may exist due to active DPF regeneration.</span><br /><br /><blink class='blink'><span style="font-size: 18px; font-family: helvetica;"><strong><strong>ACTION</strong></strong>: </span></blink><br /><span style="font-size: 18px; font-family: helvetica;">Operator should make sure the exhaust pipe outlet is not </span><br /></span></p></head>

Comment: `<blink>`??? Are you sure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace all the localized text by %@ :

```
<html> <head><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='cummins_black.css' /><p><span style="font-size: 18px; font-family: helvetica;">%@</span><br /><span style="font-size: 18px; font-family: helvetica;">%@</span><br /><br /><blink class='blink'><span style="font-size: 18px; font-family: helvetica;"><strong><strong>%@</strong></strong>: </span></blink><br /><span style="font-size: 18px; font-family: helvetica;">%@</span><br /></span></p></head>
```

And then create your localized string and load it:

```
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:html, NSLocalizedString(@"key_1", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"key_2", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"key_3", nil)];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

key_1, key_2, key_3 are defined in your Localizable.strings

Answer (score 0):

You either have to get a localized string from your server.

Or you have to **parse** the received string and replace the found strings with their localizations.

It would be much better to have a web service returning no HTML but just data (e.g. in JSON format) and you construct the HTML yourself so it is optimized for the device.